# How to access component methods from parent controller in Angular1.5

Tags: angularjs, components

I have child component MyStats that takes as input data with list and displays statistics about that list. I need to call rebuildStats function inside my component when list inside myData is updated. Since there is no $scope in components I cant add $watch. Is there way to call rebuildStats from MainCtrl? What is best way to solve it?

```
module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.statData = {};
  $http.get('..some url..').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.statData.list = resp.list;
  });
}]);

module.component('myStats', {
    'templateUrl': '...',
    'bindings': {
        'myData': '<ngModel'
    },
    'controller': function() {
      this.totalActive = 0;
      this.rebuildStats = function() {
        var cntr = 0;
        angular.forEach(this.myData.list, function (item) {
          if (item.isActive) {
            cntr++;
          }
        });
        this.totalActive = cntr;
      };

    }
});

<my-stats ng-model="statData"></my-stats>
```

**Edit:** There are 2 solutions that I use now:
    1) In the data block I changed to 2-way binding and introduced setter function that is created from within component and then parent can call this function. It doesn't use $scope but still... not sure if thats what Angular creators intended.

```
module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.statData = {};
  $http.get('..some url..').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.statData.setList(resp.list);
  });
}]);

module.component('myStats', {
    'templateUrl': '...',
    'bindings': {
        'myData': '=ngModel'
    },
    'controller': function() {
      var ctrl = this;

      this.totalActive = 0;
      this.rebuildStats = function() {
        var cntr = 0;
        angular.forEach(ctrl.myData.list, function (item) {
          if (item.isActive) {
            cntr++;
          }
        });
        ctrl.totalActive = cntr;
      };
      this.myData.setList = function (list) {
        ctrl.myData.list = list;
        ctrl.rebuildStats();
      };
    }
});
```

Second approach is to access controller via element. Like so:

```
    var getController = function(elementSelector, controllerName) {
      var el = angular.element(document.querySelector(elementSelector));
      if (el) {
        return el.controller(controllerName);
      }
      return null;
    };
```

So now if I have controller with MyTestController that has tag "my-test-controller" and has id="id1" then I can access it like:

```
var ctrl = getController('my-test-controller#id1', 'MyTestController');
ctrl.MyTestControllerMethod(); // access any exposed method
```

Answer (score 0):

If think that using ES2015 getter/setter syntax will be best solution.

```
class MyStats{
    get myData() {
        return this.$value;
    }
    set myData(value) {
       this.$value = value;
       this.rebuildStats();
    }

    ...
}


module.component('myStats', {
    'templateUrl': '...',
    'bindings': {
        'myData': '<ngModel'
    },
    'controller': MyStats
});
```

Or just inject $scope to your contoller function with $inject syntax:

```
MyStatsController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyStatsController($scope) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have to operate in old ES5 realm. I can $inject but that sounds hackish (ince there is reason why $scope taken out from component). I find it very strange that I can communicate from component to parent using function binding like 'onUpdate': '&' but there is no obvious way (if one even exists)  to call from parent to component.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird to have a classic controller+scope mixed with 'modern' components and one-way data binding.

First thing that comes to mind is that you need your component to call the service itself. You don't need an external controller and bindings.

```
var vm = this;
this.$onInit = function() {
  $http.get(...).then(function() { vm.rebuildStats(); })
}
```

Even better, put that logic inside a service and call the service in $onInit.
When the promise resolves and your data is ready, call your function.

This way you have a fully independant component and your code gets lighter and better.

If you **really** need to pass the data inside an attribute, you can use $onChanges to check for model changes:

```
var vm = this;
this.$onChanges = function (changes) {
  if (changes.myData) {
    vm.myData= angular.copy(changes.myData.currentValue);
    vm.rebuilsStats();
  }
};
```

Comment: This component will be used for data analysis from different controllers: stats for user reviews, for comments and for book reviews. Since its very generic I cant bind it to specific data source. So in that respect data has to be passed as argument. I tried $onChanges but its called only during component cration and not called when I update list from $http

Comment: No, it's wrong, it's called when bound data changes. https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and something like this worked for me:

```
var scope = $('my-stats').children().scope();
scope.$ctrl.rebuildStats();
```

`$('my-stats').scope()` is the "outer" scope of your component, you have to call `children()` to get "inside" (provided it has any children).

I don't think this is a correct way though. The docs say that `scope()` is just for debugging.